# Property Let and Set not recognized

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in Object Oriented Programming in VBA and I'm trying to write my first class.
I'm following guides on the Internet for it.
But I get errors I don't understand.

Let and Set properties are not recognized and appear in red. The same is true for Sub when I try to pass them Parameters.
Would you happen to know where the issue can come from ?

```
Option Explicit

Private pNumShare As Integer
Private pNumPlan As Integer
Private pName As String

Public Property Get NumShare() As Integer
    NumShare = pNumShare
End Property

Public Property Let NumShare(int AS Integer)
        pNumShare = int
End Property

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    NumShare = Empty
    NumPlan = Empty
    Name = Empty
End Sub

Public Sub setColonne(int As Integer)

End Sub
```

Comment: It is 'Set' not 'Let' for a Set property

Answer (score 1):

The expression `int` is a function and therefore a reserved word in VBA.  Use a different variable name.

See [here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-int-function.html)

(And please Edit your question to Add your code...Images for code are not helpful)

Also the syntax is `Property Set` as in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/property-set-statement)